# Is there a Kotlin "eval"

Tags: kotlin

I have a bunch of strings like these in my already existing and quit big template file:

```
Hello $World I say hello to $User, too
```

I was thinking I could somehow let kotlin parse/search&replace this file as a kotlin string, and I'd just have to set the variables `World` and `User` to get an evaluated string...  How is this possible?
This is not a kotlin source file, but a file that's beeing read by my kotlin program.

Why I want to do this? I used bash's `envsubst` before, and had to move away from this, since things were getting too complicated.  But now I have no easy way to replace strings in a file anymore...

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by eval, perhaps you can provide an example. But in kotlin you can make calculations inside strings, e.g. `"${1 + 1}"` will produce `"2"`

Comment: No. Kotlin is a compiled language. You would need a compiler available at runtime to be able to do that, which 99.9% of the time is not necessary, and would bloat the runtime.

Comment: I'm aware of that - I just need it :-)  I think I'll go with Javas ProcessEngine, and call envsubst on that... maybe that works.

Comment: It sounds like your needs would be met by a *template engine* (such as [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/), [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), or [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)).

Comment: Using "org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9" StringSubstitutor(variablesToReplace).replace(string) now... seems to work.  Only slight modifications to my already existing template neccessary - variables must be in the form ${varname}.  I looked at thymeleaf before, but that was more complicated in my case, because I have an existing template already.

Comment: Kotlin supports string interpolation, so why would this not work? Or do I misunderstand @Frischling's question?

Comment: I put in a clarification.  Im reading this string from a file, and StringSubstitutor worked like a charm - just don't have time right now to make an answer.

Comment: That's just string interpolation, not code evaluation. Maybe you should change the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a template engine.

You don't really need an eval (which would allow running a full Kotlin application from a String) in this case.

For example, [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) templates use a syntax that's similar to Kotlin template Strings, so a template may look like this:

```
<h1>Welcome ${user}!</h1>
```

Then, from Kotlin, you can evaluate the template with a `Map` holding the template bindings (variables the template can use) like this:

```kotlin
val user = "joe"
val bindings = mapOf("user" to user)

val cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29)
cfg.directoryForTemplateLoading = File("/where/you/store/templates")

val template = cfg.getTemplate("test.ftlh")

// write the resolved template to stdout
val out = OutputStreamWriter(System.out)
template.process(bindings, out)
```

See a Java example here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_all.html

There are many other template engines, and the KTor site lists a few:

https://ktor.io/docs/working-with-views.html

If you're using KTor, BTW, it makes it much easier to use template engines... your framework may even have similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** Please see my other answer first: you probably don't want to run a full Kotlin script just to parse some text file with variables... use a template engine for that.

It's possible to execute Kotlin scripts, i.e. `eval` Kotlin code, but it requires that you basically ship the Kotlin compiler with your application.

This GitHub project, [KtsRunner](https://github.com/s1monw1/KtsRunner), for example, does that, so you can do this:

```kotlin
val scriptContent = "5 + 10"
val fromScript: Int = KtsObjectLoader().load<Int>(scriptContent))
println(fromScript)
// >> 15
```

It requires some hacking though, is very slow and it uses a bunch of Kotlin "internal" APIs to work.

See the full list of libraries this project uses here:

https://github.com/s1monw1/KtsRunner/blob/master/lib/build.gradle.kts#L21

A ["proper" KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md#embedded-scripting) ([discussion here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/75)) exists to add first-class support for this in Kotlin, but it's not finalized yet.

Currently, it looks something like this:

```kotlin
fun evalFile(scriptFile: File): ResultWithDiagnostics<EvaluationResult> {

    val compilationConfiguration = createJvmCompilationConfigurationFromTemplate<MainKtsScript>()
    val evaluationConfiguration = createJvmEvaluationConfigurationFromTemplate<MainKtsScript>()

    return BasicJvmScriptingHost().eval(scriptFile.toScriptSource(), compilationConfiguration, evaluationConfiguration)
}
```

But it'll probably change before being released.

Comment: Don't wait up though... this proposal has been going around for 4 years now, with little progress made in the last 2 years... it just seems to be a low priority for Jetbrains, even with the Gradle Kotlin DSL work they've done to make KTS more or less performant (which it still isn't).